# Backbone model as DTO or as a POCO (POJO)?

Tags: backbone.js

I am using Backbone with .NET WCF services for my web project and I really want your opinion with the following.
When writing .NET WCF services, I have one big model with many attributes and several data transfer objects (DTOs), one for each service that returns portion of my model. I am using those DTOs for return data to the Backbone client.
I am wondering, should I create one Backbone model for each DTO (it's url will be the service url)?
Or maybe should I create one big Backbone model and fill only the data I have whenever I have it (when calling service A fill the model with A's results and when calling service B, continue fill the model with B's result)?
Using the DTOs models approach, when one model contains attribute that exists in other model, changing the first model will require me to sync the other model's data.
Using one big model will require me override the fetch and the save methods so this model will be able to interact with several services and not only one.

What do you think Backbone suppose to work like?

Comment: Why do you need one big model? Seems like unnecessary complexity given your description. Backbone's design tries to keep things simple and granular.

Answer (score 1):

As WiredPrairie suggested the Backbone approach (and, I would argue, the "smart programmer" approach) is to break things up in separate components.

Every programmer, as a human being, can only wrap their head around so much code at once.  If you try to create massive classes in your code, you essentially guarantee that you won't keep all of the relevant parts "in memory" at once.  Furthermore, just about everyone agrees that testing is a key part of code maintainability, and large classes inhibit testing.

Ultimately, you don't want a few giant classes, you want lots and lots of small classes that work together to create your app.  With that approach you can easily understand the class you're working on, because it will be a manageable size, and you can probably keep the general workings of every class that interacts with it in your head at once as well.  Furthermore, you can easily write unit tests because each class only has one purpose, and one (reasonably-sized) set of operations to test.

Backbone supports this very well; I can't say for certain, but I'm pretty sure Jeremy Ashkenas never expected anyone to just have one `View` for their whole site.  On the contrary, I'm pretty sure he expected sites (normal ones at least) to compose many `Views` together to create the site.  Similarly, trying to do everything with one giant `Model` really goes against how Backbone was designed to be used.

There are many ways you can "connect the dots" between your smaller components using Backbone.  For instance, if you really need to save all of your data at once, that doesn't mean you should have only one `Model`.  You can create one "master" `Model` that handles syncing, and then give it a bunch of properties or attributes which are `Collections` or other `Models`.  You can then override the `initialize` method to populate those `Models`/`Collections`, and override the `toJSON` method of that master `Model` to use the toJSON results of its sub-modules and sub-collections.

Or, you can overwrite the `sync` method (or the individual CRUD methods like `save` and `fetch`) on the child classes, so that when they try to `fetch`/`save`/whatever, they actually trigger a save of the master object.  Or, you can override `Backbone.sync` to watch every operation that happens and prevent ones that come from sub-objects.  Or you can ...

The point is, it's good practice for almost any programmer in any setting to connect many small parts together rather than trying to do everything at once in one place.  Because Backbone is a very powerful and flexible library, it gives you lots of ways to do exactly that.